# How can I group and sum multiple columns in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, math, sum

I'm still new to python and pandas and currently trying to get sum of multiple columns in a CSV file.

I have a CSV file with columns that I want to sum `unitCount`, `orderCount`, `invoiceCount`:

```
     date       id   name   unitCount   orderCount   invoiceCount
 2020-02-12     1   Guitar     200          100           200
 2020-02-12     2   Drums      300          200           100
 2020-02-12     3   Piano      400          700           300
 2020-02-11     1   Guitar     100          500           300
 2020-02-11     2   Drums      200          400           400
 2020-02-11     3   Piano      300          300           100
```

My desired output would be a CSV file with sum of those last 3 columns (grouped by `ID`) and linked to the latest date only:

```
     date       id   name   total_unitCount   total_orderCount   total_invoiceCount
 2020-02-12     1   Guitar        300              600                   500
 2020-02-12     2   Drums         500              600                   500
 2020-02-12     3   Piano         700              1000                  400
```

Would someone be able to help?

so far I was trying the below, but it doesn't work for me. Would be possible to add `groupby` to the first line of the below code? Or I started completely wrong? Thanks!

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path/to/myfile.csv', sep=';').sum()
df.to_csv(r'path/to/myfile_sum.csv')
```

Comment: Do you really need pandas? Cause it could to be solved generating another CSV file with calculed totals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with somewhat manual `agg`:

```
(df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
   .agg({'date':'max', 'name':'first',
         'unitCount':'sum',
         'orderCount':'sum',
         'invoiceCount':'sum'})
   .to_csv('file.csv')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
# group rows by 'id' column
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date':'max',
                                      'name':'first',
                                      'unitCount':'sum',
                                      'orderCount':'sum',
                                      'invoiceCount':'sum'}

# change the order of the columns
df = df[['date', 'id', 'name', 'unitCount', 'orderCount'  ,'invoiceCount']]

# set the new column names
df.columns=['date', 'id', 'name', 'total_unitCount', 'total_orderCount'  ,'total_invoiceCount']

# save the dataframe as .csv file
df.to_csv('path/to/myfile_sum.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `sum()` on the `groupby` object, then rename the column names accordingly and finally write the resulting dataframe to a `csv` file.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path/to/myfile.csv', sep=';')

df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['unitCount', 'orderCount', 'invoiceCount'] \
  .sum() \
  .rename(columns={'unitCount':'total_unitCount', 'orderCount' : 'total_orderCount', 'invoiceCount': 'total_invoiceCount'}) \
  .to_csv('path/to/myoutputfile_sum.csv', sep=';')
```